# How can i change the background color of the sidebar in the backend of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, customization, backend

im creating a plugin for change the look in the backend of Wordpress, and im stuck for change the background of the sidebar in the Backend, how can i change it?

[image]

Also, how can i change the icons? i want to delete the name and just be a icons.

[image]

Comment: Use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin for customizing admin dashboard

Comment: .....have you ever looked into CSS?

Comment: And if you want only icons and no text, what happens when you hover over a menu with multiple options e.g. the pages?

Comment: I will use just for one thing, i dont need the rest of the options.

Comment: I dont want a use a plugin, because im learning php and Wordpress :(

Comment: Im look the CSS, but i cant find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you want to do it yourself, you need to inspect wp-admin via Chrome Developer Tools section. Without inspecting you can't learn what is inside. (To inspect the webpage you need to press ctrl+shift+i and choose elements tab)

I give you the code which solves 2 things you want, but you need to learn inspecting for learning more about this.

Add this code to your theme's functions.php:

```
    add_action ('admin_footer', function (){

    echo '<style>
    #adminmenu,#adminmenu li,#adminmenu li ul,#adminmenu li ul li,#adminmenuwrap,#adminmenuback,.wp-submenu  
{background: red !important}

    #adminmenu .wp-menu-name,.collapse-button-label,.wp-submenu li a 
{display:none !important}

#adminmenuwrap,#adminmenu,#adminmenuback,.wp-submenu 
{width: 40px !important} #wpcontent{margin-left:40px}
    </style>';

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, ill check with the inspector, but im new in CSS/PHP/Wordpress so i cant find it, but your answer help me a lot. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add class "**folded**" in  for hide title

Example in JS

```
$('body').addClass('folded');
```